# Perl Mojolicious array loop

Tags: arrays, perl, mojolicious

Not sure if this is even possible.  But I am trying to loop over an array. I keep getting the error message `Can't use an array as a reference` on the for loop line. `$product_results->[6]` does contain data.

```
my @product_array = split(',', $order->[6]);
$product_results->[6] = \@product_array;
% for (@$product_results->[6]){
    <%= $_->[0] %>
% }
```

Comment: @{$product_results->[6]} should work.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: @RajashekarReddyM next time, write an answer to get some rep. Don't answer in comments. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using both forms of dereferencing at once.

Either use

```
$ref->[6];
```

or

```
@$ref[6];
```

Both at the same time will Perl dereference the reference as an array into something like this, and then dereference that as an array reference to get the 7th element. But that doesn't work.

```
(1, 2, 3)->[7]
```

What you actually want to do is dereference the array ref that is *inside* your seventh index in the array reference.

```
# this will deref the content of index 7
# |      this will deref $ref into an array
# |      |
  @{ $ref->[7] }
```

To illustrate forther, your data structure looks like this.

```
$ref = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    [                   # 7
        qw/ foo bar baz/
    ],
]
```